# Create a network/relationship graph with a filter and clickable nodes

Tags: python, networking, graph, relationship, networkx

I spent a lot of time figuring out a way to display my data and came across pyvis. While it works great at displaying the data in a meaningful way, it doesn't have support for filtering or clickable nodes. I need these two features for the following reasons:

1. Filtering - There is the possibility of having hundreds of nodes. It's hard to find a needle in the haystack.
2. Clickable nodes - I would really like to store data inside of the nodes that could be dynamic and show real-ish time data.

Is there a better product out there other than pyvis? I'm not attached to pyvis for any reason other than it was as close as I could get for the actual visualization part. I looked at matplotlib but I have too much data for that to work.
My other issue is that while my python skills are pretty decent, my other languages are lacking. So using something else would be challenging.

Here's a picture that shows kind of what i'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: that's odd, in the edit it showed that I inserted the image. Not sure what happened. Added back in. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please explain picture.  Are the reddish blobs the nodes?  What are the green and yellow lines?  Where are the links?

Comment: Everything in the picture is either a node or an edge. I'm using this to display IBM MQ data. So the pink nodes are QMGRs, and the rest is either a queue or a channel object.

Comment: and yes, the lines show the relationships between the nodes. For example, a message will get sent from a QMGR, to a remote queue, then over to it's destination via a channel. The edges and arrows show the direction/flow of traffic.

Comment: You are going to need a zoom function!

Comment: Some years ago I developed an application which does what you need, called graphex ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/graphex/wiki ).  If you wish, we could discuss development of a custom application for your specific needs.  Check my` github profile for contact details.